What are eigenvalues of the Jacobian in the n direction?
This problem comes from the discontinuous Galerkin method.
$F(u(G_k,t))\cdot n$, where $u = u(x,y,t)$, $F = (f(u), g(u)) = (u,u)$, $\triangle_{ij} = [x_{i-1/2}, x_{i+1/2}] \times [y_{j-1/2}, y_{j+1/2}]$, $G_k$ is a Gaussian point on the cell boundary $\partial \triangle_{ij}$; $n$ is the outward unit normal of the cell boundary $\partial \triangle_{ij}$.
The expression $F(u(G_k,t))\cdot n$ is replaced by the simple Lax-Friedrichs flux:
$F(u(G_k,t))\cdot n \approx \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(F(u^-(G_k,t)) + F(u^+(G_k,t))\right)\cdot n - \alpha\left(u^+(G_k,t) - u^-(G_k,t)\right)\right]$
where $\alpha$ is taken as an upper bound for the eigenvalues of the Jacobian in the $n$ direction, and $u^-$ and $u^+$ are the values of $u$ inside the cell $\triangle_{ij}$ and outside the cell $\triangle_{ij}$, respectively.
My problem:
I don't understand what the eigenvalues of the Jacobian in the $n$ direction stand for.
My attempt: In my opinion, the Jacobian matrix can be
$$
J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
f_x & f_y\\
g_x& g_y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or
$$
J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
f_u \\
g_u
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since $n$ corresponds to $x$ and $y$, the Jacobian should be in this former.
